# using ant svn task to get the version of a working copy?

Tags: java, svn, ant

Is there a way use the svn ant task to get the svn revision number of a working copy and put it into a variable?

I would like to add an entry in my Java manifest file which includes the svn revision number, e.g. `0.9.65361` where `65361` is the revision number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha, I found [this idea](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/02/05/apache-ant-get-the-svn-revision-number-by-exec-task/), which depends only on the `svnversion` command-line utility in SVN.

```
<project name="ant-exec-example" default="svnversion" basedir=".">
  <target name="svnversion">
    <exec executable="svnversion" outputproperty="svnversion" />
    <echo message="SVN Version: ${svnversion}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Here's where it captures the version in an ant property:

```
<exec executable="svnversion" outputproperty="svnversion" />
```

Comment: My repository is at revision `603` but your suggested command returns `603:605M`. Any idea what he `605M` means and how I could just get the `603` as a result?

Comment: The `:` means: your local working copy is not up-to-date (after a `svn update` this should be gone). `M` means that you have local modifications. See at `svnversion --help` for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways -

> 1. Use a utility - I believe you are looking for this - https://code.google.com/p/svntask/ I have used it for some side
>      projects and it works well.
> 2. Use commandline utility. - "svn info http://svn.myweb.com/myproject". To use this method simply create a
>      batch file and put this command in the batch file. Then call this
>      batch file from your ant task and get the revision number from the
>      text by searching for that starts with line "Revision:". Or you can
>      just dump the whole result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my variant to bundle svn revisions info within the application artifact:

```
<target name="svn_revisions">
    <hostinfo prefix="HOST"/>
    <echo file="${dir.out}/.revisions" message="Built by ${user.name} on ${HOST.NAME}${line.separator}"/>
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="svn" output="${dir.out}/.revisions" append="true">
        <arg line="info"/>
    </exec>
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="svn" output="${dir.out}/.revisions" append="true">
        <arg line="status -u"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="build-war" depends="compile, svn_revisions">
    <war basedir="web" file="${dir.out}/ROOT.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <!-- main stuff -->
        <zipfileset dir="${dir.out}" prefix="META-INF" includes=".revisions"/>
    </war>
</target>
```